# Connect to REST api in Gluon mobile without using gluon connect, but other libraries like Unirest

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I have been trying to connect to REST end point from gluon mobile, but i have the challenge when the app is deployed on the mobile itself. It crashes(application stopped working) every time i attempt to make the connection on button press. But all works fine when testing on the desktop. here is the code

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {

        JSONObject reqJson = new JSONObject();
        reqJson.put("username", username.getText());
        reqJson.put("password", password.getText());

        Future<HttpResponse<JsonNode>> future = Unirest.post("http://xxx.xxx.xx:8087/business/login")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .body(reqJson.toJSONString())
                .asJsonAsync(new Callback<JsonNode>() {

                    public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                        System.out.println("The request has failed");
                    }

                    public void completed(HttpResponse<JsonNode> response) {
                        System.out.println("successfull");
                        System.out.println("...");
                        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("DASHBOARD_VIEW");
                    }

                    public void cancelled() {
                        System.out.println("The request has been cancelled");
                    }

                });

    });
```

My build.gradle looks like this

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        
    }
    dependencies { 
        compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'
        compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.mysacco.MySACCO'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = '/Users/aiden/Library/Android/sdk'
        
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'NOTICE.txt'
            exclude '**/*.txt'
            
        }
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

and my androidmanifest looks like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mysacco" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
        <application android:label="MySACCO" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="MySACCO" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                        <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.mysacco.MySACCO"/>
                        <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity" />
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you checked the exception on your device? Use `adb logcat` to find out about the reason of the crash.